# Sending broadcast from the service to killed activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

i am working on my first android application and what it does is that it has an activity which after signing in starts a service that pings user location to the server after a certain time period or whenever user location changes. Now for the communication from the service to the activity I am using BroadcastReceiver.

The service after logging the location to the server broadcasts a message which my activity receives and update the UI accordingly. Now everything is good up till this point but when I delete my activity from the background while my service is still running in the background  what happens is that whenever the service logs the location on the server and broadcasts the message it crashes and a message is shown on the screen saying your application has been stopped.

I think that the android broadcast system is expecting my activity to be alive to receive the broadcast and when it doesn't find it then it crashes the service.

What I want is that if my activity is around it will receive the broadcast but if it is not then the broadcast should be ignored. It should not crash my service.

I am following proper steps by registering for the service in onResume() and unregistering in onPause(). Moreover I am registering the service dynamically rather than in the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing a stupid mistake there. I was passing the references of variables defined in my activity to the broadcast service. It worked fine when my activity is still alive but when my activity was killed the service ended up with null pointers which upon updating crashed the service.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `bindService(intent)` not `startservice(intent)` for indefinite internal of time.so it would work till your activity is binded to your service when you finish activity then call `onUnbind()`.

onDestroy()in activity call stop service.

check in manifest that your receiver is not registered there.